# selecting string that ends with specific string using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

string is "$$$ dkfdjkfj **name** $$$ kdfjdf **post** 
dkfdjkfj **name**  **name**

selecting only string that starts with $$$ and ends with **name** or starts with space and ends with **name** and should not have any html tags in between.

Above output is: dkfdjkfj

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to use regex?

You can do it with built in string functionality, for example:

```
if(myString.StartsWith("$$$") && myString.EndsWith(name) && (!myString.Contains("<") && !myString.Contains(">"))) DoSomething();
```

You might want to create some more advanced html tag logic. My example assumes that a < and a > in the same string is a html tag.

**Edit**: 
I misunderstood your question. You can use substring, example:

```
var str = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("$$$")+3, myString.IndexOf("name")-3);
```

The indexes are +3 since you don't want to include $$$ or name. If you have many valid sub strings in one string, you have to iterate through it and remember the last index of $$$, and search for the next one from that position.

Comment: how to select all the text from this string and getting into new string?? i don't have to test for the existence of this pattern but have to select the text also that's why need Regex